# Does there exists any non-zero bounded function which satisfies Mean Value Property on $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

A function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{C}$ is said to satisfy Mean Value property on $\Bbb{R}^n$ if for all $x$ we have $f(x)=\frac{1}{B(x,r)}\int\limits_{B(x,r)}f(y)\ dy$ for all $r>0$.

I have proved that there does not exists any $L^p$ non-zero function which satisfies the above property using Holder's inequality where $1\le p<\infty$. How to check the $L^\infty$?

Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Constant functions have this property and they belong to $L^{\infty}$.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville's_theorem) for a proof. You can disregard the harmonicity assumption as only MVP is used (I am not sure if they are equivalent).